# Unity won't compile project successfully

Tags: unity

I am trying to build the project into a Web GL, but it throws 3 errors when it reaches the "Building additional assets" stage.

> ### Error 1
>
> Building - Failed to write file: resources.assets
> UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
>
> ### Error 2
>
> An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the
> build: Asset: 'Library/unity editor resources' (You are probably
> referencing internal Unity data in your build.)
> UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
>
> ## Error 3
>
> Error building Player: Couldn't build player because of unsupported
> data on target platform.

Things to note:

- I do not use NGUI or any other third-party GUI solution, but Unity's
  new UI system
- I have tried versions 5.2.3 and higher and it still has returned me
  errors
- I have one DLL LitJson that is used to parse JSON files
- Project includes StreamingAssets and Resources folders
- Error occurs even if I try building on other platforms such as
  Windows. Same errors are returned
- I am using a custom font downloaded online
- Blacksmith's Character "Challenger" is also included
- I thought the project folder has been corrupt so I decided to migrate
  all assets to a clean project. No changes

Any idea how do I fix these?

Thanks in advance!